# Countdown timer with with circle border animation preserving values on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created the countdown timer with circle border animation. Border of circle fills as timer increases. The timer value is preserved even on page refresh. Only problem is on page refresh border of circle animates weirdly and then shows properly.

You can check demo here https://codepen.io/parag-rohankar/pen/qMomMG

```
//HTML Code 
    <div class="item html">
    <h2></h2>
    <svg width="60" height="60" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="dummy_circle">
     <g>
      <circle id="circle"  r="26" cy="30" cx="30" stroke-width="2" stroke ='#e8eff7' fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>      

    <svg width="60" height="60" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="timer_circle">
     <g>
      <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="26" cy="30" cx="30" stroke-width="2" stroke ='#ff0000' fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

//JS

```
    var time = 60;
    var initialOffset = 164;
    var i;
    var timer_content;
    var rotation_class;
    var border;




    //Initial content of timer for page load and on page refresh.
    localStorage.getItem("local_i")===null? timer_content='Now': timer_content=localStorage.getItem("local_i"); 
    $('h2').text(timer_content);

    //Check local storage if it has contdown value if yes then take it from local storage else start from 1;
    localStorage.getItem("local_i")===null? i=0: i=localStorage.getItem("local_i");

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (i == time) { 
            localStorage.removeItem("local_i");
            localStorage.removeItem("local_border");    
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }       
        localStorage.setItem("local_i", i);
        localStorage.setItem("local_border",initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time)));

        //Dispaly couter value(if in local storage get from dispaly from it else dispaly normal calculated value)
        localStorage.getItem("local_i")===null ? $('h2').text(i):$('h2').text(localStorage.getItem("local_i"))

        localStorage.getItem("local_border")===null?border=initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time)):border=localStorage.getItem("local_border")
        //border=initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time));
        $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', border);

    i++; 

}, 1000);
```

///css code

```
    .item {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }

    /*.dummy_circle { width: 132px; height:132px; border-radius:50%; border:8px solid #000000; position:absolute; top:5px; left:7px;   z-index:1}*/

    .item h2 {
        text-align:center;
        position: absolute;
        line-height: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    svg.timer_circle {
        z-index:2;
        position:relative;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); transform: rotate(-90deg);           
    }
    svg.dummy_circle { position: absolute; left: 0; top:0; z-index: 1}
    .circle_animation {
      stroke-dasharray: 164; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
      stroke-dashoffset: 164;
      transition: all 1s linear;
      stroke: #ff0000;

    }
```

On page refresh i want border to be start filling from its current position. 
Can someone please provide solution to this.

Comment: We are not going to simply "provide a solution", as many says "we're not a free code service". You need to show us your effort. What have you already tried to achieve your desired result? What is the problem you are facing with **your attemp**?  And please, resume your code to just [mcve]. This will help a lot the people who will try to help fixing and finding a solution to the problem you face

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.getItem()` returns a string and you use that returned value in calculation without converting it to a number. This causes unpredictable behavior since adding string to a number is rarely what you'd expect and want.

Pro tip: use typed flavor of javascript (i.e. typescript or flow, or purescript or even elm).

```js
console.log(3 + "12")
```